# Sequelise find function not working with postgres datasource

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js, find

I am trying to do a simple find from postgres table using sequelize find function.
But the function is neither returning any result nor the exception.
It would be great if anyone can share some insights that could help resolve this issue.TIA.

Code Snippet :

```
let data = {'where': {'created_at': {$between: ['2023-09-08 00:00:00', '2023-09-09 00:00:00']}}};
return Location.find(data)
        .then(function(result){
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        });
```

Location is my model for the table. There is no response when I try running this function.

Comment: I don't use sequelize, but don't see `find` here [Finders](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-finders/). I do see a `<model>.FindAll()` example here [Model basics](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/): `Post.findAll({  where: {authorId: { [Op.eq]:  }  }});`

Comment: The reference you followed might be old, because `find` is deprecated (in favor of `findOne`/`findAll`), and `$` is deprecated (in favor of `Op.`)

Comment: @RanHalprin Tried with findAll and Op as well, still it did not work.
However, if I try the exact same snippet with node v8.16.1, it works.
Thanks anyways for responding to the query.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with node version v14.21.1.
Because when I tried the same snippet on 8.16.1, it works.
Will further evaluate and update here when I find anything else.